# Can I use return to stop execution in a generator function?

Tags: redux-saga

In the code below, I use return to stop execution of the generator function and let the saga that called the generator continue running. I don't understand exactly what is happening behind the scenes. Is the use of return in the code below fine or will it have unintended consequences?

```
export function* getSessionToken(user: string | CognitoUser, redirect: string = '') {
    try {
        return yield call(refreshAwsSession, user, 'sessionToken');
    } catch (error) {
        if (redirect) {
            const search = '?redirect=' + encodeURIComponent(redirect);
            yield put(push({ pathname: '/signin', search: search }));            
            return;
        }

        yield put(push('/signin'));
    }
}
```

Comment: Using `return` is sagas is expected and it should work fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sagas are [generators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*) under the hood, so it's ok to use `return`:

```js
function* a() {

  yield 1;
  return 2;
  yield 3; // never goes here
}

const a1 = a();

console.log(a1.next().value);
console.log(a1.next().value);
console.log(a1.next().value);
```